# Type Mismatch. Error in ADO export from Excel to Access

Tags: excel, vba, ado

I'm currently using VBA to transfer data to an access database from excel.

I am able to run the code below to transfer the data from my 35 column excel table into my 35 column access table but I receive this error every time I do. I did not receive this error prior to it being 35 columns. Please could you explain where I am building in this error?

[image: Error Description]

```
   Sub CopyDatatoAccess()
    Dim DatabaseConn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim DatabaseData As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim Pathway
    Dim x As Long, i As Long
    Dim nextrow As Long

    On Error GoTo errorhandler:

    Pathway = Sheet18.Range("AP2").Value
    nextrow = Sheet18.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


    Set DatabaseConn = New ADODB.Connection

    If Sheet18.Range("A2").Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "ARF form is not present for Upload"
    Exit Sub
    End If

    DatabaseConn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Pathway

    Set DatabaseData = New ADODB.Recordset

DatabaseData.Open Source:="ARFs", _
    ActiveConnection:=DatabaseConn, _
    CursorType:=adOpenDynamic, _
    LockType:=adLockOptimistic, _
    Options:=adCmdTable

For x = 2 To nextrow
    DatabaseData.AddNew
    For i = 1 To 35
        DatabaseData(Cells(1, i).Value) = Sheet18.Cells(x, i).Value
        Next i
        DatabaseData.Update
    Next x

    DatabaseData.Close
    DatabaseConn.Close

    Set DatabaseData = Nothing
    Set DatabaseConn = Nothing

MsgBox "The ARF is now uploaded"
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


   On Error GoTo 0
   Exit Sub
errorhandler:

    Set DatabaseData = Nothing
    Set DatabaseConn = Nothing
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure Export_Data"
    End Sub
```

Comment: A data type mismatch means you're trying to put data into the column that does not match the column's data type.  You can figure out which column it is using the debugger to step through your `for` loop until you reach the field that causes the error. We don't have your spreadsheet or your table to use to do that for you, so you'll need to do it yourself.

Comment: Thanks Ken! Still quite new to VBA, apologies for the very basic question

Comment: No problem. :-) When you figure out which field is causing the issue, you should be able to tell what's causing the mismatch. If not, you can ask here and we'll try to help figure it out.

Comment: Aside - This is a quintessential reason to use Excel only as the end use application (i.e., graphing/reporting) and not as data source for database. Access as a database maintains strict data type rules while Excel *anything* can be written in *any* cell! Consider using Access datasheet forms that resemble spreadsheets and will warn user of wrong input.

Comment: Hi @KenWhite I used the Debugger and stepped through the first row (row 2) of the for clause from i=1 to i=35 and there did not seem to be any issues with that (all i values were ok)  i added in ERL into the error message box and it didnt state the name of the line with the error. Not sure what I should do as my next step

Comment: It could be the first row, or the third row, or the 400th row. You could always look at the table to get a list of the data types for each column, and then visually scan the data for something out of place (e.g., finding *ABCD* in a spreadsheet column being assigned to a database column of type *Integer* or *Date*). And @Parfait is absolutely correct - if you stop trying to use Excel as your data entry tool and instead properly create an Access form that can validate the data as it is entered, you won't have these issues.

Comment: Please comment out "On Error GoTo errorhandler:" by putting an apostrophe before the line to disable your error handling, then run the code. When the error happens click Debug and tell us what line is highlighted.

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks for your help and yes I understand that this would be better if it was all in access. (its excel based because i inherited an excel based form that I havent been able to pick apart). The issue was that the next row function was going to row 13 even when there was only 9 rows with data. This seemed to cause the error. This is now fixed :) Thanks for showing me how to use debugger!